# Python regex matches but won't sub immediately afterward

Tags: python, regex, django

I am trying to change settings.py by regex instead of by hand. I have a regex that matches all of installed apps and grabs all except the last paren:

```
rgx = "(?P<start>INSTALLED_APPS.*?)\)"

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
)
match = re.search(rgx, content, re.DOTALL)
```

grabs

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
```

but for some reason when I go to sub it, with a new app, like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'my-new-app',
text, n = re.subn(rgx, new_string, content, re.DOTALL)
```

it doesn't sub anything. I ran as subn and proved it wasn't matching. This makes no sense, because I am using the exact same regex that just made a match. How can I get the exact same regex to match and then not match the exact same string?

Comment: Your new input string does not end in a `)`. Right? Then, there can't be a match.

Comment: good point, but that wasn't an issue- I was speaking of an entire settings.py file, which has many more parens. ty though, based on my example that was a good guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `re.DOTALL` for the `count` argument. Use it for `flags` instead:

```
re.subn(rgx, new_string, content, flags=re.DOTALL)
```